# VS 2012 Debug error

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug windows 7 64bit machine, which runs remote debugging tools.
I`m compiling my code in my local computer and then I copy it to remote machine and run it with remote debugger.

It used to work until this sunday, and I don't recall any special changes or installations done around that time. 
Since Sunday, everytime i'm trying to run remote debugger (F5) I get this build error

> 1> ------ Build started: Project: Messaging, Configuration: Debug
>   Dynamic x64 ------
>
> 1> The operation cannot be completed because BeginBuild has not yet been called.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

**Edit :** I changed "On run, when projects are not up to date" to "prompt to build" and then is seems my projects were outdated. I can't understand why.. myabe it`s the reason and the "BeginBuild has not yet been called" is just the sympthom?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Got the same thing with VS Express 2013. A mere restart did the trick.

Comment: Restarting works, but after a very short while it gets awfully tedious. Could anyone know a permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 10):

I had this same issue.
Removing the `.suo` file helped for me, but I have found people who reinstalled Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my laptop solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS2017 (15.9.3)

Restarting the computer did not help.

Removing the `.suo` file helped. I searched for it was located in the `.vs\Devices\v15` subdirectory.